# Android studio new project not starting

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio and everything went well.

And when I try to create New project, name of the application and everything is done, but after clicking finish, nothing is happening.

I have read that for the first time it takes sometime to start, but for me even after 10-15 minutes of waiting, nothing is happening-no error message display or failed to start report.

What am I supposed to do? Is there anything else that I am missing?

Comment: Did you try to re-install / update Android Studio ?

Comment: gradle build takes some time when you create new project. You will find its status on left bottom side of android studio window.

Comment: make sure you have the latest version of Android Studio
check out here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I think gradle build is already done. There is no status display anywhere

Comment: I tried reinstallation.The same problem persists.